# Solve Probability of Distribution

Tags: equation-solving, probability-or-statistics, distributions

Why does this work:

```
Solve[Probability[x <= t, x \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[]] == 0.95 ,t]
```

But this doesn't:

```
Solve[Probability[x <= t,x \[Distributed] StudentTDistribution[2.964, 2.071, 5]] ==0.95,t]
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: `Solve` is an exact symbolic solver ... it works mostly with linear equations and polynomials and special cases like the Erf function which it knows how to invert. Since your problem is numerical anyway, try `NSolve` instead of `Solve`.

Comment: Same problem with NSolve. Doesn't work.

Comment: Works for me .... what version of Mma are you using?

Comment: Works for me too, but try `FindRoot` when `NSolve` doesn't work.  `FindRoot` won't find all roots, just one, but it can handle any "black box" function.

Answer (score 2):

(This may be better as a comment)

This may be an exercise in testing the use of NSolve (which does produce the answer [Version 9]) the normal distribution and StudentTDistribution can be solved with `Quantile` or `InverseCDF`, as can be verified by testing solutions.

```
Quantile[StudentTDistribution[2.964, 2.071, 5], 0.95]
```

or

```
InverseCDF[StudentTDistribution[2.964, 2.071, 5], 0.95]
```

both yielding:

7.13717

Comment: Thank you very much! That helped a lot!